# c# Json Deserialization expression

Tags: c#, json, expression, deserialization

maybe someone know the solution. I can't deserialize expression.

**Client side**:

```
 var expresion= (Expression<Func<Company, bool>>)(model => model.Id ==id);
 var respond = new JObject();
 respond .Add("Expression", JToken.FromObject(expresion));
```

**Server side**:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor;
T p = (T)serializer.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(jObject), typeof(T));
```

**Exception**:

```
{"Unable to find a constructor to use for type System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[HostStorageModels.Company,System.Boolean]]. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'Expression.Type'."}
```

Comment: It tells you what is wrong, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/6bee/Remote.Linq

```
var query = (Expression<Func<Person, bool>>)(model => model.FirstName == "test2");
var remoteExpression = query.ToRemoteLinqExpression();

var request = new Request<Person>
{
       Items = new List<Person>()
       {
          new Person() { FirstName = "test", Id = 1 },
           new Person() { FirstName = "test2", Id = 2 }
       },
      Expression = remoteExpression
};
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, serializerSettings);
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request<Person>>(jsonString, serializerSettings);
var expresion = result.Expression.ToLinqExpression<Person, bool>();
var filtered = request.Items.Where(expresion.Compile()).ToList();
```

Comment: You may want to use `Remote.Linq.Newtonsoft.Json` nuget package that makes things even easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is explicitly telling you that there is no constructor to build the Expression. If you check [Expression Constructor ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd324093(v=vs.110).aspx) in the MSDN documentation, you will see that it is protected. You could try to send the expression in other serializable format and re build it when you receive it at the other side.

Comment: maybe someone knows that rebuild way?